# Good explanation about how rails works behind the scenes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was wondering if there was any good articles out there that explain how the architecture of rails works, i.e how it handles the server connection, how it queries the database so easily etc.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Take a look at the blog of Yehuda Katz. He wrote a bunch of articles about the architecture of Rails, like [this one](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/06/11/rails-edge-architecture/). Watch [The Renegades Guide to Hacking Rails](http://intridea.com/2008/9/21/slides-code-from-rails-internals-tutorial?blog=company). Try to find and read [that book](http://www.manning.com/black/), it has a good chapter about the internals of Rails.

I forgot to mention the excellent [Under the hood](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/under-the-hood) series by Jamis Buck. He really describes how the certain parts of Rails work.

You may also dive into [the Rails sources](http://github.com/rails/rails/tree/3-0-stable). They are well commented, easy to read and understand. Read them just like any book.